# Let $f$ be a continuous mapping of metric spaces $X$ into $Y$, and let $E$ be a dense in $X$. Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $f$ be a continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, and let $E$ be a dense subset of $X$. Prove that $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$

---

**My Attempted Proof**

$E$ is a dense subset of $X$. Therefore $x \in X \implies (x \in E\ \  \text{OR   $\ x$ is a limit point of $E$} \ )$

We need to prove $y \in f(X) \implies (y \in f(E) \ \text{OR $\ y$ is a limit point of $f(E)$} \ )$

Since $y \in f(X)$ and $E$ is dense in $X$, then $y \in f(E)$, if $x' \in X \implies x' \in E$. It's left to show that $y$ is a limit point of $f(E)$ if $x$ is a limit point of $E$

Take $E^{\alpha}$ to be the set of all limit points of $E$ in $X$, that are not in $E$. Then we have

$$E^{\alpha} = \left\{a \ |\  a\in X \ , \ a \not\in E \ \ \text{and every neighborhood of $a$ contains $q \in E$ }\right\}$$

Then for every $\alpha \in E^{\alpha}$, every neighborhood of $\alpha$ contains a $q \in E$. Thus for $f(\alpha)$, every neighborhood of $f(\alpha)$ contains a $f(q)$ where $q \in E$

It we put $y' = f(\alpha)$, then $y'$ is a limit point of $f(E)$, and $\alpha$ is a limit point of $E$

And thus we have $y \in f(X) \implies (y \in f(E) \ \text{OR $\ y$ is a limit point of $f(E)$} \ )$ as desired $\ \square$

---

I just wanted to know if my proof is logically and rigorously correct. If my proof is nonsense, or illogical in any way please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is fine and works for all topological spaces, not just metric spaces, but you need to justify this assertion:

> Thus for $f(\alpha)$, every neighborhood of $f(\alpha)$ contains a $f(q)$ where $q\in E$

It’s true, because $f$ is continuous, but nothing that you’ve said shows this, and it’s the crucial point.

I will say, though, that I think that you’re doing it the hard way. A set $D$ is dense in a space $Z$ if and only if every non-empty open set in $Z$ contains a point of $D$. (This is easy to prove.) Now let $Z=f[X]$ and $D=f[E]$, and let $U$ be a non-empty open set in $Z$. Then $f^{-1}[U]$ is a non-empty open set in $X$, since $f$ is continuous, so $E\cap f^{-1}[U]\ne\varnothing$, and there is an $x\in E\cap f^{-1}[U]$, and clearly $f(x)\in D\cap V$. $V$ was an arbitrary non-empty open set in $Z$, so $D$ is dense in $Z$.

Comment: @BrianMScott Thanks for this answer, would simply stating that $f$ is continuous then constitute a rigorous enough proof? With regards to the easier proof you mentioned, I noticed that you used square bracket notation $f[X]$ to denote the mapping on $X$, as opposed to the $f(X)$ notation Rudin uses, is it standard convention to use this notation?

Comment: @Perturbative: You need to say a little more than just that $f$ is continuous. I would let $U$ be a nbhd of $f(\alpha)$, use continuity of $f$ to say that $f^{-1}[U]$ is a nbhd of $\alpha$, note that there is some $x\in E\cap f^{-1}[U]$, and finally observe that $f(x)\in U\cap f[E]$. \\ I prefer to reserve the notation $f(X)$ for the case that $X$ is an *element* of the domain of $f$; when $X$ is a *subset* of the domain, and I want the image of that set, I use $f[X]$. This is a standard notation, though obviously not everyone uses it.

Comment: @BrianMScott Ah okay I see. Thanks for all your help, it's much appreciated.

Comment: @Perturbative: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is two separate proof ideas mixed into one.

- The direct variant $y=f(x)$, $x$ limit point, $x_n\to x$, $f(x_n)\to f(x)=y$.
- Or the indirect variant starting with $y$ is not a limit point of $f(E)$, $f(E)$-empty ball around $y$ results in $E$-empty ball around $x$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is confusing. I guess you mixed up some arguments together. It's actually quite simple:

Let $y_0 \in f(X)$. Then there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$. Because $E$ is dense in $X$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n \in E^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x_0$. The sequence $(f(x_n))_n \in f(E)^{\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(x_0) = y$ since $f$ is continuous, thus yielding us the density of $f(E)$ in $f(X)$